# How to draw a sector in OpenGL ES?

Tags: android, opengl-es

i'm korean development for android & opengl.

Sorry that i do not like English.

I'm doing draw the "Marine Map" with S57 data.

So. want to draw a "LIGHTS".

Android in Opengl es1.1 tell you about how to draw a pie shape would be appreciated please.

Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a triangle fan using GL_TRIANGLE_FAN like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Mr. Clay answered

I think this way is the tried.

However, this method can not be displayed using the angle.

I want to draw an angle with.